# A more efficient convex hull algorithm

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Before I start, I would like to say that this is for a programming project of mine I'm doing but I figured my question is only about the part involving math so here I am.
So in Grahams Scan algorithm, you have to find the point with the lowest y coordinate and start with that. But why not just start from the point with the lowest polar angle?In Grahams Scan, you need to sort the points based on their polar angle so you are not doing anything extra in the algorithm I mentioned.
P.S: Although finding the lowest item in a set is real fast, in HUGE cases it takes A LOT of time.

Comment: The polar angle is calculated relatively to the first point not relatively to $O=(0,0)$. The reason we choose $y_{min}$ is because we are sure this point belong to the convex hull (in fact any extremum in a given direction belongs to the convex hull) and that other points are in the same half-plane (i.e. have apolar angle between $0..\pi$). See an animation here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps1idzOx6LA

Comment: @zwim but can't we say the point with the lowest polar angle is always on the convex hull?

Comment: No take $5$ points $A(-1,-1)B(-1,1)C(1,1)D(1,-1)E(\frac 12,0)$ then $E$ is inside the square $ABCD$ yet it has the lowest polar angle $0$ for angles between $0..2\pi$. If you take angles between $-\pi..\pi$ just rotate this figure for another counter-example.

Comment: @zwim I'm sorry I should have mentioned this but assume the points all have positive coordinates

Comment: In this case it would work. (because the fictive point $O$ could serve as $y_{min}$ and then second point is guaranteed to belong to convex hull).